# Select multiple data from two tables in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: posts and comments. The identifier column in posts is `post_id`. Each comment has also `post_id` to point to the responded post.

```
posts             comments
- post_id         - comment_id
- message         - message
- time            - time
                  - post_id
```

What I need: Select posts, and also the comments posted on each selected post.

What I do now: I have two queries.

1. First query to select posts, then I loop thru it, save all `post_ids` into an array.
2. Then second query to select all comments based on the saved `post_ids` from previous step.
3. Then I loop the comments and adds them to the posts variable.

What I want to do and don't know how: get posts and comments in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
select * from posts join comments on posts.post_id = comments.post_id
```

Hope will do the trick.

Comment: The problem with this is that it only fetches one comment. And I need all comments per post.

Comment: If you statement is true, it only means that your data integrity is broken. In you `comments` table you're supposed to have all comments with unique `comment_id` and same `post_id` for comments that belong to same post. If @sgt's query doesn't work either the table data is wrong or (?!) you're not fetching all rows of query (?!)

Comment: I have unique comment_id per comment, and each comment has post_id to the correct responded post. @sgt's query works but only fetches one comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` concept. For more information see http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database.

Comment: Join, in the way I know to use it at least (like in the example of @sgt), returns only one comment per post. While there may be multiple comments per post.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data that is on your SQL?

Comment: There's not much to show. Think of the simplest situation: 1 row in posts, 3 rows in comments (all of the same post). I want to select all this data in one query. When I use join, it really join data from comments, but only from one comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` clause:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM posts AS p, 
       comments AS c
 INNER JOIN posts ON p.post_id = c.post_id;
```